# My senior colleague has less technical skill than me, doesn't want to learn on his own, but keeps asking me to teaching him everything

Tags: work-environment

I have been frustrated for a long time. We were originally a small company that got bought by a larger company. This colleague of mine, lets call him 'PH', he was the office manager in the original company, now in the larger company, he is just like me but more senior due to years of service, and nothing more. I say this because he doesn't have a lot of technical skill (programming/coding etc) and he usually doesn't go learn things on his own, but instead, every project we take on, I was the one that got things all setup and running, then he would come back and have me teach him how to do everything, what's more, he would constantly stand by my office door and "chat" with me about project ideas, then present them in meetings, this kind dynamics have been going on for years, now we are in the project, again, I got everything working and wrote all of the programming codes and also designed the algorithm with our primary contractor, but our higher up boss wants me to teach everything to PH so he can present everything in a client meeting, this is driving me crazy! Should I contact our regional manager to at least express my concern? or I don't know, leave... Please help.

I am thinking to write an email to my regional manager who is higher up than our current manager (since he is the one that ask me teach everything to PH), to explain the situation and the history of this type dynamics, I am a very good writer, so I am sure I can strike the right tone etc, what do you guys think?

I think here is a bit context, our office has shrunk to just 3 people, and PH's senior position is a legacy from before we were bought by the bigger company, but now we are really the same, just project engineers, but he is somehow still considered as more senior than me simply because of years of service. I have much higher level of technical skills and education level than PH.

Comment: Either move on or continue to support him...

Comment: @SolarMike, really? that's it? no other recourse? is this really how dark workplace can get?

Comment: Well, how are you going to change? You recognize what happens but still do it... Don't blame it on the workplace...

Comment: @SolarMike so you are saying I should just refuse to "help" him? actually I've arranged to work from home full time now so as to get away from his constant pestering...

Comment: Just wait, there will be a constant stream of phone calls or emails... But I would like to be wrong...

Comment: @SolarMike you are right! he had done that. So do you think I should write an email to our regional manager (over our current manager) to explain the situation? I feel that I have good relationship with our regional manager...

Comment: From what you said in the comment you made to the answer, no-one recognizes your contribution so how will you get them to change? Moving on is an option to consider & get recognized for your contribution...

Comment: What makes you upset about the situation?
Has PH's behaviour negative impact on your work?
Are your own contributions not properly recognized by your company?
Does it seem unfair that PH is a senior and you are not?

Comment: @Helena, yes, he is ostensibly the "senior" engineer, he is supposed to tell me how to do things, but he needs me to tell him how to do things and give him ideas, always.

Comment: @Fattie, really, so I am not alone I guess, then I guess the 'PH' way of life indeed is prevalent in the workplace, my goodness...

Comment: hi ForComment - it is absolutely commonplace that new programmers suddenly realize that software development is ........... an utter shambles.  There are a million posts on here from new programmers stating that either (1) the manager is an idiot (2) the software engineering is a total shambles (3) there is no documentation at all etc etc etc. This is normal.   What you have to understand is that ***this is the very reason, that if you are actually good, you can make an insane amount of money***.  I always find it very confusing when people *are sad* that software engineering is a shambles.

Comment: (.. ) So, I always find it confusing when people are **sad** that software engineering is a shambles.  Just one aspect of the "software shambles" - to pick merely one - is the "hobbyist infestation".  Because it is *quite easy* to in fact *program badly*, you get a million incompetents throwing together scripts.  Some look at that situation and say "Wow.  How depressing. How sad."  I look at that situation and say **"Oh my God, no wonder it's SO EASY for me to have all these Ferraris"**.  So I get confused by - for example - yourself complaining "My manager is an idiot".  That is GOOD NEWS !!!

Comment: @Fattie, ok I am bit unclear about your post's relevance to my issue at hand in general, one thing for sure, PH is NOT my manager, and I wouldn't say he is idiot, but clearly less competent than me.

Comment: @Fattie, if you are saying that the fact that I discern that PH is a shitty software person would somehow lead to me "having all these Farraris", one thing for sure, PH is NOT my manager, and I wouldn't say he is idiot, but clearly less competent than me, AND he makes MUCH MORE than me! and I still teach him on how to do things, tell me if this is fair to anybody. Hard to imagine this is a ***common*** issue.

Answer (score 10):

You say your higher boss wants you to teach PH ... to present everything in a client meeting.

With what you've described, to be honest, that seems like a good call to make from your boss's perspective, if PH isn't great at the technical side, but used to be a manager, he's good at communicating the work to clients.

I think before acting, you should be clear on what exactly your problem is, and what you're trying to achieve.

Do you want to do PH's job and go present to clients? Are you any good at that? Have you gotten buy-in from the business for your projects from higher up? If not, you should see this more as a partnership. Realize that without selling it to the business and its clients, the tech is literally worthless.

So whether you think you're good or not - learn from the guy. He definitely knows how to present the product and himself.

Don't be angry at him for doing what he's good at.

To get more buy-in from PH, and get him to learn the tech side a bit if you need him to, you'll have to have a good relationship with him. Mutual understanding helps. And I'm sure you'll pick up a thing or two.

Or you just let the guy do his thing, make sure you're credited for your work - but it does sound to me like your boss's boss is aware you're doing most of the tech work - and just be happy you don't have to go to the meetings.

Being mad at PH is not serving you well. Move past it.

Comment: I am NOT trying to do PH's work AT ALL. It is just the dynamic of him needing me to give him both technical know how and project ideas, then seldom give me any credit in public that made the environment toxic, please know that I have no problem with him presenting to the client, just internally within our own group, all I am asking is to be recognized as someone who did critical work within the company, no more no less, but I am not getting recognized at all. Oh, I had my Ph.D. degree in engineering and published in scientific journals, I am a master presenter.

Comment: As someone commented on your question, I'm not sure why you're so upset. If you don't want the job PH is doing, what is your objective?

Comment: my objective is to not have him as a useless layer above me on everything I do, because he doesn't really contribute on actual meaningful work, just a mouthpiece transmitting what I said to him and what I taught him on everything, and he doesn't put in the effort to learn things, he would go on vacations at the beginning of difficult project, then come back to pick the fruit of my work.

Comment: So he's presenting your work to the business and clients?
I'm not trying to wind you up. I am trying to give you a different perspective on how some of what he's doing has a value, which you seem to be dismissive of.

Comment: I've been working with him for quite a while, he is NOT good at explaining things, and the one time couple years ago he tried to "direct" a project on his own (he pushed me out of the project after I did the foundation layer of work), the final product (an analysis tool) was completely wrong and effectively useless. I always has the mentality of live and let live, so I am not dismissive of anything he does, I just don't want to have anything to do with him at all.

Comment: Well I can hardly challenge your assessment without knowing the guy. Personally, I would refrain from writing that email, and make the best of the situation, especially if I'm not even interested in doing the job. I would not enter such a political move without knowing how I want it to play out, and being fairly certain I have buy in from others in the company. If it bothers you that much, though, your evaluation may well differ.

Comment: I know, that's why I am trying to get other people's perspective here, I am still mulling about that email, perhaps to tell the regional manager that PH needs to receive further training so as to contribute to projects effectively, and suggest that he take on his own project etc etc, what do you think?

Comment: I guess it has to be said, I think he is good at suckup and doing superficial things to elevate his visibility. We are doing this project that has shared google doc drive. We update the design document periodically. He would download the design doc on the day of meeting, then somehow jiggle a few words, then save it so as to have it displayed on the google drive as "PH updated this today", you know this is the kind of things he constantly spending his time on doing during the day while others are hard at work on real projects.

Comment: About the presentation, it is strictly about the algorithm, design logic and inner workings of the software that I built for the project. Why would it be assumed that PH as a past manager (who didn't really market well in the past, that's why we got sold due to poor workload in the first place), automatically good at explaining technical details on this new project that uses technology that he has never been exposed to before now? in fact, as I mentioned earlier, he is bad at such technical presentation.

Answer (score 1):

It's one thing for this "senior" to ask you to help him and teach him.  It is a totally different thing when your higher up boss asks you to teach everything to this person.  Typically you should do what your boss asks of you unless you want to face disciplinary action at your company.

As for PH, don't speak with him unless necessary.  If he approaches you to try and get ideas from you ( to later present as his own ) don't give him any.  Play dumb or say something like:

> That's a really good question PH, I will think about it and get back to you.

When he asks you to teach him something, rather than actually explaining it just tell him:

> I am sorry but I am currently working on X for the boss.  The code is well commented, you should have no issue understanding it.

Comment: I have already done these steps, as I mentioned, I even arranged to work from home most of the time just to get away from his constant pestering, but I think what I felt is this constant under appreciation for my work and contribution, what I really like is to do the job and get recognized for it in the form of 'oh, TT did that part, but I seldom get any mention in meetings and they always gloss over my work.

Comment: @ForComment Being asked by your boss to teach someone else the work you have done is a form recognition

Comment: ok, this is certainly a new perspective, I have to say. But the truth is that there is really no need for him to take on the things that I have been working on, because he doesn't really do any real meaningful work, just understand enough to present it, which I can do it myself effectively anytime. Please be clear, he is NOT my manager and we are at the same level in the company, he is just older, that's all.